# listView lag The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, listview

I created a Gallery that get the image from an *External Storage*, and also i decreased the height resolution of images but i got this :

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be 
                 doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Also my `ListView Lag`.

What should to remove the `Lag`?

Here it is my Code :

```
ListView mList;
ArrayList<File> list;

Bitmap firstBitmap;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));


    context = getApplicationContext();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mList.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter());






}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile (String file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file), options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    Log.d("Width","Bitmap : "+reqWidth);


    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file), options);
}

class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null){

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item_template,viewGroup,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder._vw_blayer =  view.findViewById(R.id.vw_blacklayer);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_background);
            holder.imageViewround = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_cover_d);


            view.setTag(holder);
        }else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        firstBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(list.get(i).getAbsolutePath(),600,316);

       holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(firstBitmap);
      //  Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(i)).into(holder.imageView);

      //  Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(i)).into(holder.imageViewround);
       holder.imageViewround.setImageBitmap(firstBitmap);




        Log.d("getItem","I"+getItem(i));


        ObjectAnimator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder._vw_blayer, View.ALPHA, 1f,.3f);
        fade.setDuration(1500);
        fade.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        fade.start();


        return view;
    }
}



ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root){

    ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].isDirectory()){
            a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));

        }else {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")){
                a.add(files[i]);

            }

        }
    }
    return  a;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    View _vw_blayer;
    ImageView imageView,imageViewround;

}
}
```

Comment: Use an [image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Or, do something else to move loading your bitmaps off the main application thread.

Comment: I suspect that `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile()` is causing your issues. I would recommend looking into image caching, and only calling that method when no cached decoded image exists. Unfortunately I can't think of any classes off the top of my head, thus a comment and not an answer.

Comment: i already used a picasso but the probleme wasn't solved, the probleme is caused by the size of images which exceeds the 3Mb ,I think that i should load all of my list in the on create method, if you can help me by an example that will be perfect and thank you.